# Помогите разобраться с асинхронным использованием InternetReadFile(и не только)

Tags: c++, многопоточность, winapi, асинхронность, wininet

Здравствуйте! Только начал изучать асинхронный подход, и столкнулся с проблемой, помогите разобраться.

Задача такова: получать откуда-то данные в виде `char`, и затем что-то с ними делать(в моём случае, использовать как текст на кнопке). Код, который сейчас приложен ниже, слишком медленный. Больше всего времени уходит на получение данных: дело в том, что функция `Get(int id)` загружает данные из интернета посредством `WinInet`(синхронно), отправляя Post методы, и возвращая ответ.

```
void some_func()
{
for(int i(0);i<10;i++)
   for(int q(0);q<5;q++)
     {
       char data[100];
       strcpy(data, get(i,q)); // i, q - просто какие-то идент. данные искомого

       button[5*i+(q+1)]=new Button(data);
     }
}
```

**Первый вопрос**

Как вообще решать такую проблему(общий случай, то есть, если `get` никак не связанна с интернетом, но выполняется долго)? Мне приходит в голову, что нужно каждый `get` в отдельном параллельном потоке выполнить. Если правильно думаю - то как это сделать? Ведь я же не могу создавать 50 потоков, и при этом вызывать одну и ту же функцию. 50 функций?

**Второй вопрос**

Как это реализовать в плане `WinInet`? Смотрел на MSDN, но как-то сложновато понять со старта, может объясните по-проще?

Comment: Я так понимаю, у вас InternetReadFile используется?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов да. По 1024 байта в буфер, а потом `return`

Comment: @АртурКлочко офтоп но все-таки, отделите получение данных от собственно создания кнопок, получайте данные более крупными блоками, например на форме у вас 30 элементов, выгружаете все 30 одним запросом и потом создаете всю форму.

Comment: @Cerbo, я не использую формы, только WinApi

Comment: @АртурКлочко У вас упомянут button видимо для примера, ну вот и считайте что форма тоже для примера.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, как-будто у меня не может быть своего класса Button